# Not able to preserve history for certain time while merging two repos in GIT

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket, git-bash

I had a repo structure like this before 1 year :

repo1/
subrepo2/
.
.
.

before one year I moved the subrepo2 to its separate repo so I created 2 repos :

repo1/

and

subrepo2/

for one year I made changes to both the repos and now I have to merge them back preserving history.

**when I am trying to follow the steps available in most of the questions, I cannot see the history for that one-year**, and I do not want to lose it.

Please help.

the steps I followed for merging them back :

in subrepo2 branch:

```
git filter-branch -- --all
mkdir subrepo2 
mv * subrepo2
git commit -m "moving everything in a directory"
```

then in repo1 branch

```
git remote add migration feature/migration <path to>/subrepo2
git pull -f migration --allow-unrelated-histories
git remote -rm migration
git commit
```